# android : filtering column data

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello I have a table like this in my sqlite3 database.

```
db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"   + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, " + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_SUB_CATEGORY + " TEXT, " + KEY_AMOUNT + " REAL, "
        + KEY_NOTE + " TEXT " + " );");
```

I  queried the database and got all values for `KEY_SUB_CATEGORY` and `KEY_AMOUNT` for current Year.

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] { KEY_SUB_CATEGORY, KEY_AMOUNT }, + KEY_YEAR + "=? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(currentYear) }, null, null, null, null);
```

Now, is there a way, I can further filter based on the values in my `KEY_SUB_CATEGORY`.

For example, my `KEY_SUB_CATEGORY` has 3 values  for Grocery.

Is there a way I can get the total amount value for Grocery from this Cursor? Or do I have to query seperately for each `KEY_SUB_CATEGORY` every time?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get the total amount value for Grocery from this
>   Cursor? Or do I have to query seperately for each KEY_SUB_CATEGORY
>   every time?

I recommend to you to make new query(code is more readable) and then use `SUM()` function that makes a trick.

```
int sum = 0; 
String query = "select SUM(" + KEY_AMOUNT + ") from " + DATABASE_TABLE 
             + " where " + KEY_SUB_CATEGORY + " = ?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"Grocery"});
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
   sum = c.getInt(0);
}
```

Output will be:

```
select SUM(KEY_AMOUNT) from DATABASE_TABLE where KEY_SUB_CATEGORY = 'Grocery';
```

Comment: But I want to know if I can query the database just once and get all the values for KEY_SUB_CATEGORY and then filter the values for Grocery, Fuel etc and their total amount from the cursor?

Comment: @kavya i prefer separated queries. its more readable for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
new String[] { KEY_SUB_CATEGORY, KEY_AMOUNT, "sum(" + KEY_AMOUNT + ") as catsum " }, 
+ KEY_YEAR + "=? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(currentYear) }, 
KEY_SUB_CATEGORY, null, null, null);  

c.getInteger(2) would be the sum
```